# How to use editUrl attribute of jQgrid in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to implement edit/add of rows in jqgrid dynamically but stuck at place with editUrl attribute. Can somebody tell me that

1) Where to keep this php file, in server or in our applcation?

2) I am using like `editurl: './data_save.php',` and I have this file in my application, next to my jsp file. But on submit, I am getting 'error Status: 'Not Found'. Error code: 404' on top of popup window and on console I am getting, no mapping found for request with URI [/myapp/some.php] in distacherservlet with name 'myApp'.

Any idea?

**Update :-**
I also tried using, editurl:'/some.jsp' and when I create on controller(expecting this url) in my Spring MVC Controller class then I do not get message at console saying, "no mapping found for request with URI [/myapp/some.php] in distacherservlet with name 'myApp'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your application name

```
editUrl:'WhatEverYourApplicationNameIs/data_save.php'
```

Update1:

```
editUrl:'@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")'
```

Update2:

If your edit method is like below

```
public .. MyEditMethod()
{
//Add logic
}
```

then your editUrl will be

```
editUrl:'@Url.Action("MyEditMethod","WhatEverYourControllecNameIs")'
```

Comment: Thanks @janina. Its working. There are some other errors too bbut I'll work on that. Thanks a lot once again. I was struggling with this for longtime.

Comment: I am doing Form Editing. Its working in case of "Edit" but not for "Add". The error is same i.e.  404 (Not Found)

Comment: See If there is any mismatch,Because It should.In update your question and show yor pager's code.

Comment: Ok, if I use @Url.Action. Control will go to my java code, right? If yes, then how I'll get my new (edited or added) rows data into my contoller. And what should be the value of 'ActionName'. Is it 'edit' or 'add' or 'delete'?

Comment: For your first question: I think it should,I am working asp.net mvc and here it works fine.For your second question, ActionName is whatever you give the name of your method.See update.

Comment: Ok but how the data will be passed to my method.